# How to filter call stack in Eclipse debug view for Java

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, callstack

While debugging, the Debug view in Eclipse shows the call stack. Which is great. But I'd love to be able to filter out all the call that I definitely don't care about, such as Spring and the JUnit runner.

Here's an example of my call stack right now. I'd like to keep the entries in bold, while hiding all the rest. Is it possible to do in any way? (plugin, next Eclipse release, configuration, ...)

```
com.myproject.mymodule.MyFinderObject.fetchDestinationSettings
com.myproject.mymodule.MyFinderObject.compareCurrentSettings
com.myproject.mymodule.MyFinderObject.compareSettings
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed
com.myproject.caching.CachingInterceptor.invoke
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke
$Proxy43.doSthWith
com.myproject.mymodule.MyFinderObjectTest.testSettingComparisonForCurrentSettings
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
com.myproject.mymodule.MyFinderObjectTest
com.myproject.mymodule.MyFinderObjectTest
com.myproject.mymodule.MyFinderObjectTest
junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect
junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected
junit.framework.TestResult.run
com.myproject.mymodule.MyFinderObjectTest
junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest
junit.framework.TestSuite.run
org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestMethodReference
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main
```

Comment: And by the way, do you think this would make for a sensible feature request?

Comment: Sure - it doesn't sound that hard, either.  Going to poke around the debug APIs.

Comment: @espinchi, I use this feaure in IntelliJ and it helps a lot.

Comment: There is a feature request in eclipse bug tracker: It was reported in 2009 and is still in state "NEW": https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=273194
(This comment does not help solving the problem, but at least other people interested in this, don't have to search the eclipse bug tracker, too)

Comment: And another ticket in Eclipse Bug Tracker: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=513499 (from 2017, status: "ASSIGNED")

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way I know of to filter the stack trace view is via Mylyn.  If you have an active Mylyn task, and you click the "Focus on Active Task (experimental)" button in the Debug View, then the stack trace will be filtered to only show those methods that are in the current task's context.

In this case, you wouldn't be filtering certain items from the stack trace; rather, everything would be out by default, and only certain items would be displayed (those in the task context).

You can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543588/what-do-the-different-kinds-of-eclipse-content-assist-do/1623482#1623482) answer for more about Mylyn.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This would be certainly too restrictive for my case. Still, if nobody proposes anything better, I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: You can create a task and add all your code to the context, and there you have what you want. I didn't try it though. The only problem I can think of is Mylyn may try to remove long-not-touched items from the context.

Comment: "Mylyn may try to remove long-not-touched items from the context". I think this can be changed in the Preferences: unselect General > Editors "Close editors automatically" and also check the settings in Mylyn > Context, especially those in the "Editors" group.

Answer (score 13):

**Preparation:** You can use [step filters](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-debug_view.htm) as described [here](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2011/10/17/effective-mockito-part-4/). Then whenever you step-debug through your code, it will not jump into excluded packages or classes, e.g. from the JDK or some frameworks like Hibernate or Spring. But this is just a prerequisite.

**Solution:** The stacktrace still contains frames from those those packages. In order to filter out those as well, you need to patch the *Eclipse JDT Debug UI* plugin. [Someone else](https://www.intersult.com/wiki/page/Eclipse%20stackfilter%20plugin) has done that already for older Eclipse releases up to Indigo. Because I was curious if I could get it running in the current release Luna 4.4.1 as well, I recreated the other guy's changes and pushed the ***[Debug View + Stack Filter Plug-In](https://github.com/kriegaex/Eclipse-Debug-View-Stack-Filter)*** to GitHub including a download link to the patched plugin. So if you are also on 4.4.1, you are lucky and do not need to patch and compile anything by yourself. Just use my version. Otherwise please clone my repo and look at the changes, then apply them to the plugin version of your choice.

Comment: hi, i have tryed to put org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui_3.6.300.201412061413.jar in the dropin folder of eclipse but nothing seems to happen... any idea ? thanks you

Comment: No idea. Do you use exactly Luna 4.4.1 or another Eclipse version? And which debug.ui version is currently installed before dropping in the replacement?

Comment: I tried to build a new version for 4.5.1, but did not manage to do it. Although it is more of a Problem with building Eclipse. Can you maybe explain a bit more how you built the plugin after changing the source?

Comment: I don't really remember how I did it, but I am trying to help quick & dirty: I cherry-picked my commit to R4_5_1 tag, built the class files in Eclipse (something goes wrong in Maven), downloaded the original JAR from Eclipse and manually patched the one class file into it. Try [this link](http://scrum-master.de/download/eclipse_debug_stackfilter/org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui_3.7.0.v20150505-1916.jar), see if the JAR works for you (untested!) and please provide some feedback.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your comment until now. I tried your JAR and it works! Thanks very much! I tried building the whole package with Maven, but it always used the unpatched source-code for some reason. So maybe manually patching the single file would have worked for me as well. But thanks now it works well for me.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific, please? "It does not work" is not a particularly good problem description. You do not even define "it". What did you try?

Comment: I am trying for step filtering in eclipse oxygen 4.7.3 to hide
 NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0( ) in call stack using the latest jar for 4.5.1 ( that you gave above). But this method is not getting filtered out. Please help ! here is one screenshot : [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCvg0.png)

Comment: Actually I have not been using or maintaining this tool anymore for a while. Feel free to fork my repo and create a pull request if you get it running with whatever Eclipse version you use. It is open source, after all. I assume the principle is still the same.