# Android + Edit Step Filters in Eclipse debugger perspective?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

How do I filter stacks when debugging Android applications?  I've selected .java from the list in the "Edit Step Filters" dialogue, but it didn't help.  Can I add a filter or package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "you can't." The step filters only apply when you're stepping with the debugger. [Apparently Mylyn can do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988505/how-to-filter-call-stack-in-eclipse-debug-view-for-java), but there's no generic support.