# How to filter dynamically generated classes in debug view?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

When I debug in Debug View I can see dynamically generated classes. Is there any way to filter them?

for example

> SomeService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$61115062.invoke(int, Object, Object[])
>   line: not available    MethodProxy.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 149 
>   Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Object, Method,
>   Object[], MethodProxy) line: 617

there is a lot of it and it makes code harder to debug.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable step filtering in the debug view, and configure it in window/preferences/java/debug/step filtering

[image]

Comment: This is `Step Filtering`, i.e. for `Step Into (F5)`, the `Debug view` is the thread and stack list. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988505/how-to-filter-call-stack-in-eclipse-debug-view-for-java