# Eclipse Debug UI (how to filter the stackTrace)

Tags: eclipse, debugging

when I debug, I would like to see just the thread and the classes that I use in my application...I mean, showing the full stack trace is just noise. Do you know a solution with eclipse Luna, a plugin ?
Thanks you,

Comment: I would argue that there is a point in seeing those classes sometimes. sometimes the error happens in the underlying code, or the caller. I'll see if I can find something anyway

Comment: I don't think there is much better to find than [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27332733/126945). I'd say your question is a duplicate of that question, also.

Comment: @Gnoupi, yes this is true, but I am hoping a better solution, moreover I have to speak with the author of the post mentioned because I didnt succeed to have the functionality working. feel free to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter call stack in Eclipse debug view for Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988505/how-to-filter-call-stack-in-eclipse-debug-view-for-java)

Answer (score 0):

You could name all your threads (or use custom ThreadFactory in Executors) and filter based on that.