# Different types of eclipse java completion proposals

Tags: eclipse

In eclipse completion  proposals

> Java -> editor -> content assist -> advanced

There are 3 types

- Java Non-Type proposals
- Java Type proposals
- Java proposals

What is the exact difference between them. What is the last one "Java Proposals",  by its name doesnt it include previous two ie "All proposals" ? So why it is there.

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543588/what-do-the-different-kinds-of-eclipse-content-assist-do) but it doesnt seem to answer this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, Java proposals consists of both Non-type and Type proposals. So enabling all of them would result in duplicating potential output.

The difference between type and non-type proposals is more straightforward: type proposals allow references of Java types (available in the classpath), while non-type proposals include attributes, etc.

Comment: Ok your comment might be the answer. But what is still confusing to me is why "Java proposals" option is there. If somebody wants both Type/Non-Type, he can just check the 2 checkboxes. Why one more option which again includes them (duplication).

Comment: By default, it checks the Java proposals. However, you could replace the proposal engines independently, if you like, or mix two of them. Yes, it is redundant, but we have to live with it now.