# eclipse not inserting "diamond" operator in a java 8 project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a maven project configured to use Java 8 and all works fine, eclipse compiles code like:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

It even complains about old-style code ("redundant specification of type arguments") when I set this on the Error/Warnings tab. The problem is, I can't work out how to make it use this syntax by default on autocompletion - I'm pretty sure I saw it working earlier but now whenever I ctrl-space to insert a constructor, it insists on adding the parameters, which I don't like.

Can anybody hint what setting to check to make content assist insert <> instead of < String,String >? Or perhaps it's related to the fact I'm using Java 8 not Java 7, or that I'm on maven?

Comment: which eclipse and what's the java compiler eclipse is using?

Comment: Are you positive that your project's target java version (*not* the JRE setting) is at least Java 7?

Comment: It was STS 3.5.1 and it was definitely using Java 8 as I don't even have other version (JDK or JRE) installed. Project's target version was fine too. Turned out I must have messed something up in the Content Assist settings (could have been also that a Scala plugin I installed and later removed changed something, or some other plugin for that matter). In any case, Marco's tip below has helped and now it works again, autoinserting diamond syntax. :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I had this issue just a few minutes ago and solved it half way through typing out an SO question.

Eclipse's auto-complete apparently prioritized the old-style generic syntax after I had fiddled with the advanced content assist settings a while ago. Try resetting `Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced` to defaults; this was what fixed it for me and returned auto-complete to inserting the diamond syntax by default.

Comment: I have the same issue but unfortuately, resetting does not solve it for me (and I use Java 8 code compliance).

Comment: Amazing. This fixed my problem too, and I have a practically fresh install. All I did was import a maven project and set up some comment templates. Seems like the defaults aren't really the defaults.

Comment: Also never touched these settings.  I think this has something to do with Eclipse trying to push MyLyn.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543588/what-do-the-different-kinds-of-eclipse-content-assist-do

Comment: Thanks for this. I was curious about the actual proposal kind and it turns out to be 'Java Proposals' was switched off in my preferences.

Comment: Still the same in Eclipse 2020-06: Checking "Java Proposals" (which is also done by clicking "Restore Defaults" as suggested) fixes the auto-complete. OOTB, only Mylyn's "Java Proposals (Task-Focused)" is checked and leads to the old-style auto-complete...

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem but the solution to set everything to default didn't work for me. What worked for me is `Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced` and unchecking **JPA Proposals** in the upper window.

Answer (score 7):

I tried the two other solutions mentioned here, but none of them worked for me. What worked for me was `Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced` and checking `Java Non-Type Proposals` in the upper box.

On a different installation, this also had to be checked in the lower area, but it worked in both eclipse installations.

Comment: not worked for me, what worked for me is Java > compiler, set the compliance level to 1.8 instead of 1.7

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is enabling/checking `Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced >`**Java Proposals**. (Upper part of the settings page)

Answer (score 0):

I observed this error when compiling with maven. To solve it, I had to fix my JAVA_HOME environment variable to the right JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that different proposals are in different lists of suggestions, I think that diamond operator constructor is in "Java Non-type Proposals", while the one with arguments is in "Java Proposals". When both lists are included in the default suggestion list, the latter option goes first (though you can still press arrows to select the "diamond" one). The only option how to sort it so it was the first in the list (and hence get inserted by [ctrl+space, enter]) for me was disabling the other ones:[image]