# Add an Eclipse save action to automatically infer type (for List, Map, Set, etc)

Tags: java, eclipse

I was wondering if there was a way to have Eclipse automatically infer type for generics as a save action. So you can currently do stuff like format, organise import, add final, etc. Is there a way to do something custom?

For example, if I have the following:

```
List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I'd like that when I save, it will update to:

```
List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841572/eclipse-not-inserting-diamond-operator-in-a-java-8-project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an Eclipse plugin that uses the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.cleanUps` extension point to contribute a new Save and/or Cleanup action.

The [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_api_contributing_a_cleanup.htm) has a basic example, doing anything useful requires a good knowledge of the [Eclipse JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html)