# Eclipse content assist inserts Java generic types in constructors when not required - How to disable?

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, content-assist

Eclipse content assist for Java inserts generic types on right hand-side when they are not required. How can I disable this?

Example:

Content Assist for:
`List<String> strings = new ArrayLi`... (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdkPt.png))

results in:

`List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();`

But what I'd like would be

`List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();`

The String type is not required on the right hand-side and I prefer Eclipse would not insert it.

The Eclipse Preferences contain Java/Editor/Content Assist -> "Fill method arguments and show guessed arguments". If I deactivate it the content assist results in:

`List<String> strings = new ArrayList();`

which is also not what I want since this will not infer type arguments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [eclipse not inserting "diamond" operator in a java 8 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841572/eclipse-not-inserting-diamond-operator-in-a-java-8-project)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse Auto Complete: Java 1.7 Generics Diamond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984135/eclipse-auto-complete-java-1-7-generics-diamond)

Answer (score 0):

Ok what fixed the issue was tweaking the settings under `Java/Editor/Content Assist/Advanced` and uncheck "Java Proposals", "Java Type Proposals" and "Java Non-Type Proposals" and use "Java Proposals (Task-Focused)" instead.

By only having "Java Proposals (Task-Focused)" checked, content assist will always insert empty diamonds on constructors.

Comment: Alternatively, you can clean up the code via save actions, e.g. to replace `List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();` with `List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();` on save.